# Validate currency textbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, validation, textbox

I'm using WinForm. I have a textbox and a button.

Goal: The button should validate if the textbox is a currency format. If the textbox is a currency format, a message should display currency format. If not then a message should display Error wrong format.

Example of currency format:

$1,234.00

$12,345.00

$123,000.00

$1.00

Update:

This is what i had, but this is wrong.

```
    Private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
        currencyTextbox = Convert.ToString(textBox4.Text);

        string money = currencyTextbox;

        string s = currencyTextbox;
        float f;
        if (float.TryParse(s, NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol 
            | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowThousands, 
            CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"), out f))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ok");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong");
        }
     }
```

Test cases:

$12.00 - OK

$12,000 - OK

$12,3,00 - OK - (Invalid)

$12,3,00# - Wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A number (`decimal` in this case) is not the same than its string representation (as a currency in this case). That's why you have to firstly analyse the input from a string point of view (is the format met?) and then from a numerical one. There are some ways to perform the analysis in one go (as proposed in other answers), although they don't deliver the determination you are after (i.e., it is a currency or not; understood as mere numbers are wrong).

Sample code:

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Note: ideally, curCulture shouldn't be defined here (but globally or  
    //passed as argument), but otherwise my code would be somehow incomplete.
    CultureInfo curCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US", true);

    bool isOK = false;
    string[] temp = totalTextBox.Text.Trim().Split(new string[] { curCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    if (temp.Length == 2 && temp[0].Trim().Length == 0)
    {
        decimal outVal = 0m;
        if (decimal.TryParse(temp[1], out outVal)) isOK = true;
    }

    MessageBox.Show(isOK ? "currency format" : "error wrong format");

}
```

Note a couple of things:

- `curCulture` is expected to hold the format you want (you might even
  account for different cultures/currencies/formats). From your example, it seems that you
  want: `CultureInfo curCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US", true);`.
- The analysis of the input string can be as complex as required. For example: in the posted code, I am also making sure that the currency symbol is located in the first position.

---- UPDATE (accounting for decimal parsing problems with thousands separators)

After having confirmed that the proposed `Decimal.TryParse` (and other equivalent approaches) doesn't deliver what is expected when thousands separators (group separators) are involved, I decided to write the code below which takes care of this kind of issues. 
In any case, bear in mind that I am not too experienced in these situations (i.e., dealing with wrong decimal inputs accounting for thousands separators) and that's why am not sure whether there are more efficient ways to face this problem (although the proposed analysis is certainly quick).

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Note: ideally, curCulture shouldn't be defined here (but globally or  
    //passed as argument), but otherwise my code would be somehow incomplete.
    CultureInfo curCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US", true);

    bool isOK = false;
    string[] temp = totalTextBox.Text.Trim().Split(new string[] { curCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    if (temp.Length == 2 && temp[0].Trim().Length == 0)
    {
        isOK = isDecimalOK(temp[1], curCulture);
    }

    MessageBox.Show(isOK ? "currency format" : "error wrong format");
}

private bool isDecimalOK(string inputString, CultureInfo curCulture)
{
    bool isOK = false;

    string[] temp = inputString.Split(new string[] { curCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    if (temp.Length > 2) return isOK;

    int outVal0 = 0;
    if (!int.TryParse(temp[0], NumberStyles.AllowThousands, curCulture, out outVal0)) return isOK;
    else if (analyseThousands(temp[0], curCulture))
    {
        isOK = (temp.Length == 2 ? int.TryParse(temp[1], NumberStyles.Integer, curCulture, out outVal0) : true);
    }

    return isOK;
}

private bool analyseThousands(string intInput, CultureInfo curCulture)
{

    string[] temp2 = intInput.Split(new string[] { curCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    if (temp2.Length >= 2)
    {
        if (temp2[0].Trim().Length == 0) return false;
        else
        {
            for (int i2 = 1; i2 < temp2.Length; i2++)
            {
                if (!curCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyGroupSizes.Contains(temp2[i2].Length)) return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for explaining. This code gives me an red error lines under { curCulture. How do I make it valid.

Comment: @LearningToCode I am explaining it in my comments below the code: define it as you wish. I guess that `curCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");` is what you are looking for. Write this line above bool isOK = false; Will edit my answer right away just in case.

Comment: Maybe I wrote it out wrong. This is how i wrote it::  { curCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US").NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol }, StringSplitOptions.None);

Comment: @LearningToCode Take a look at my updated answer (also read the comment I wrote).

Comment: @LearningToCode the right version of what you tried is: ´{ new CultureInfo("en-US").NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol }, StringSplitOptions.None);´

Comment: I read through your comment. I ran it through this test case. $12,12,000 - Your code accepts this, which should be incorrect.

Comment: @LearningToCode You are right. the default TryParse doesn't make its work on this situation. This was just a sample code to illustrate the point; although I will do some tests to see what is wrong there.

Comment: @LearningToCode Note that I am not too used to thousands separators (not something common in the cultures I usually rely on). After some tests and some quick search, it seems a deal of a problem. There is a different Decimal.TryParse overload (equivalent to the float one you are trying) accepting quite a few configurations, but I did some tests and there is no easy solution. This answer was expected to be focused on the string/number difference (honestly never doubted upon the Decimal.TryParse capabilities until now)...

Comment: @LearningToCode... If I would have this problem, I would face it from a string analysis point of view (i.e., not just the first format analysis, but also the numerical parsing by splitting on account of the thousands separator). This answer is worthy upto the point of dealing with decimal including thousands separators.

Comment: @LearningToCode After waiting a bit and not seeing any answer addressing these issues, I have written the proposed string-based analysis. The new code in my answer deals with all your inputs properly (and in principle with any other situation involving thousands separators). In any case and as said, I am not completely sure that this is the most efficient solution for this problem.

Comment: Since the parsing is so specific, try to use the `CultureInfo(string, bool)` constructor. I'm the kind of person that changes these settings and like to break peoples programs ;)

Comment: @Caramiriel In any case, bear in mind that this kind of so specific approaches are expected to deal with narrowly-defined conditions (default "en-US" in this case). Otherwise, the code might account for the current culture in the computer, whatever it is.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use regular expression:

```
var moneyR = new Regex(@"^\$(((\d{1,3},)+\d{3})|\d+)(\.\d{2}){0,1}$");
if (moneyR.IsMatch(yourValue))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Ok");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Wrong");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To check format you can try to parse it in float like that:

```
        string s = "$123.78";
        float f;
        if (float.TryParse(s, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"), out f))
        {
            // OK
        }
        else
        {
            // WRONG
        }
```

Comment: I tested this. This gives me an error. This code accepts $12,3,00 which is not true.

Comment: Please look at second parameter of TryParse method, I used "Any", but it will allow such abnormal numbers. Put there NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint instead of Any and look at result

Comment: The code seems to almost work. These are the test cases $11-Correct
$11.00-Correct
$11,000.00-Wrong
$11,000-Wrong
$11,00-Wrong

Comment: @LearningToCode Add a `NumberStyles.AllowThousands` and take a look into [NumberStyles Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @RubensFarias I added `NumberStyles.AllowThousands` to it. The code is still incorrect. Test Cases:   (123,0,1 - Correct)
(123,0,1.00 - Correct)
(123,0,1.00@ - Wrong)
(1234 - Correct)

Comment: You got the technique and the reference. You can play alone now ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it should be work

```
string money = "$12,345.00";
float f;
if (float.TryParse(money, NumberStyles.Currency, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"), out f))
{
   // valid
}
else
{
    // invalid 
}
```

Debug Information:
[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: I think someone voted it down because it was similar to another answer. I tested this code and it is invalid. This code accepts: 22,2.3 @X-TECH

Comment: I have also check it on my machine, it working 100% correctly

Comment: It is probably also downvoted because it is a simple code snippet dump without explanation or anything else. The OP most likely will learn few/nothing from your answer.